# Как сделать анимацию экрана?

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, android-fragment

Добрый день. В приложении в базовом Activity находится **ListView**. Задача состоит в том что бы по клике на *list item* происходил слайд на второй экран с **WebView** и в него подгружалась переданная ссылка, а в навбаре появлялась кнопка **назад**, при клике на которую возвращаемся в ListView.

Спасибо.

Comment: И причем тут вообще viewPager и фрагменты?

Comment: У Вас заголовок темы не соответствуют описанием проблем. Как и не ясна в чем именно проблема. Как сделать анимацию слайда? Или как передать урл? или как этот урл подгрузить в webview? или же вообще все вместе?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте при старте

```
 startActivity();
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.yuo_anim, R.anim.yuo_anim);
```

Кнопка назад на экране c WebView и анимацией при закрытии

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   .....
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
   .....
        }

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.yuo_anim, R.anim.yuo_anim);
                    return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Т.е. Вы хотите аналогично с iOS поведением. Можете сделать "в лоб":

1. Создаете `ListView`, заполняете необходимым содержимым.
2. При нажатии на элемент, создаете intent, складываете в него необходимую информацию, запускаете `Activity` с `WebView`: `startActivity(intent)`
3. В `ToolBar` добавляете кнопку с необходимым изображением/надписью, которая при нажатии будет закрывать `Activity`.
4. Прикручиваете нужную анимацию.
5. Все рады результату, Вы восхитительны.

Comment: а на фрагментах такое можно сделать? так как желательно что бы в приложении было одно Activity

Comment: @VitalyPugach, можно, тогда при нажатии на `ListView` элемент делайте `replace` фрагмента, а для кнопки `onBackPressed()`, соответственно, в зависимости от фрагмента, задаете видимость кнопки.